# How use docvars in Quanteda to create document variables from raw text

Tags: r, text-mining, corpus, quanteda

I am using Quanteda to analyze party platforms, which are txt files. I have binded two sets of party platforms into one dfm:

```
 corp20dr <- corp20d + corp20r
        summary(corp20dr)`
    Document-feature matrix of: 28 documents, 6,595 features (85.0% sparse).
    > summary(corp20dr)
    Corpus consisting of 28 documents:

            Text Types Tokens Sentences
     akdem20.txt  1895   7624       332
     azdem20.txt   908   2921        94
     cadem20.txt  3255  19881       150
     medem20.txt   355    863        39
.....................................
     wvgop20.txt  1419   5013       106
     wygop20.txt   428   1085        45
```

I would like to compare the Democratic (corp20d) and Republican platforms (corp20r). But, I seem to need to use docvars to make comparisons between the different groups (15 Dem, 13 GOP). When I use textplot_keyness, I intend to get a comparison of all the texts, but the result is to draw the first text against all other texts in the corpus.

````
corp20dr_dfm <- dfm(corpus(corp20dr), 
                          remove = stopwords("english"), stem = TRUE, remove_numbers = TRUE, ```
remove_punct = TRUE)
corp20dr_dfm     
         
result_keyness <- textstat_keyness(corp20dr_dfm)
textplot_keyness(result_keyness,
                 color = c('blue', 'red'))
````

The result is a comparison of the Alaska platform to the "reference" which seems to be the other 27 documents. I was hoping to use the compare differences in word usage between the two groups of corpora (15 Democratic platforms compared to the 13 Republican platforms), but I seem to have to identify each group using docvars. But I am not sure how to do this. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The keyness function only compares one reference document to all others, so you should group the documents by the original corpus, before calling `textstat_keyness()`.  You can do this by using `dfm_group()` on a new docvar that identifies the corpus.  See below for a reproducible example.

```r
library("quanteda")
## Package version: 2.1.2

corp_a <- corpus(data_corpus_inaugural[1:5])
corp_b <- corpus(data_corpus_inaugural[6:10])

# this is the key: identifying the original corpus
# will be used to group the dfm later into just two combined "documents"
corp_a$source <- "a"
corp_b$source <- "b"

corp <- corp_a + corp_b
summary(corp)
## Corpus consisting of 10 documents, showing 10 documents:
## 
##             Text Types Tokens Sentences Year  President   FirstName
##  1789-Washington   625   1537        23 1789 Washington      George
##  1793-Washington    96    147         4 1793 Washington      George
##       1797-Adams   826   2577        37 1797      Adams        John
##   1801-Jefferson   717   1923        41 1801  Jefferson      Thomas
##   1805-Jefferson   804   2380        45 1805  Jefferson      Thomas
##     1809-Madison   535   1261        21 1809    Madison       James
##     1813-Madison   541   1302        33 1813    Madison       James
##      1817-Monroe  1040   3677       121 1817     Monroe       James
##      1821-Monroe  1259   4886       131 1821     Monroe       James
##       1825-Adams  1003   3147        74 1825      Adams John Quincy
##                  Party source
##                   none      a
##                   none      a
##             Federalist      a
##  Democratic-Republican      a
##  Democratic-Republican      a
##  Democratic-Republican      b
##  Democratic-Republican      b
##  Democratic-Republican      b
##  Democratic-Republican      b
##  Democratic-Republican      b
```

Now we can go through the steps of forming the dfm, grouping, and getting the keyness statistics.  (Here, I've removed stopwords and punctuation as well.)

```r
# using the separate package since we are moving textstat_*() functions
# to this module package with quanteda v3 release planned in 2021
library("quanteda.textstats")
corp %>%
  tokens(remove_punct = TRUE) %>%
  tokens_remove(stopwords("en")) %>%
  dfm() %>%
  dfm_group(groups = "source") %>%
  textstat_keyness() %>%
  head()
##   feature      chi2            p n_target n_reference
## 1    love 11.236174 0.0008021834       10           1
## 2    mind 10.108762 0.0014756604       11           3
## 3    good  9.971163 0.0015901101       17           8
## 4     may  9.190508 0.0024327341       38          31
## 5     can  8.887529 0.0028712512       27          19
## 6   shall  7.728615 0.0054352433       23          16
```

Comment: thank you! I did have to update R to 4 (I had been using 3.5) to get quanteda.textstats. But, this code did the trick. Thanks again.